# Why is table inside flex box not adjusting when tab is changed in size?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a navigation bar on the top of my website using Flexbox that will change in size according to the size of the tab. But with the code below the navigation bar is not changing in size as I change the size of my tab.

```css
.flexbox_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #476f95;
}
.top_table{
    background-color: #194a7a;
    width: 1422px;
    height: 120px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}

.top_table_cont{
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.td_top{
    padding: 50px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox_container">
<div class="top_table">
    <table class="top_table_cont">
        <tbody>
            <td class="td_top"><a href=#ab_me>about me</a></td>
            <td class="td_top"><a href=#projects>projects</a></td>
            <td class="td_top"><a href=#cntct_me>contact me</a></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added a missing closing `</div>` in your code.

Comment: The table is not resizing because it's container `.top_table` has a fixed width set. You need to get rid of that.

Comment: Please **do not use tables for layouts**. ["Tables must not be used as layout aids. Historically, some web authors have misused tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout. This usage is non-conforming ..." is WHATWG's stand on it.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element)

Comment: I have used your advice and implemented said changes and now my website looks and functions the way I intended it to, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `flex-direction:column` and you are good to go.